# How to get ID dynamic in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am making dynamic input, when the user clicks "**Add From Checklist**" there will be an input form, and if clicked again "Add From Checklist" then the input form becomes two and so on, for the actual select code there is already data such as
'**1-022020-001**', now for inputting stations and equipment, the data is where the value '**1-022020-001**' is in the database, now I'm still confused about how to get results from value '**1-022020-001**' can be sent to the controller and returned to js to display the input Station and Equipment.

**DEMO:**

```js
var html = '';
    $('.btnSend').attr('disabled', true);

    $("#inputCode, #inputStasiun, #inputPeralatan").select2({
        placeholder: "Choose one",
        allowClear: true
    });

    var runNumberAdd = 1;
    $("#add-more").click(function() {
        html =
        '<div class="col-sm-6 control-group">'+
            '<div class="panel panel-default" style="padding: 10px;">'+
                '<div class="form-horizontal">'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                        '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tanggal</label>'+
                        '<div class="col-sm-10">'+
                            '<input name="inputTgl[]" type="date" id="inputTglClone'+ runNumberAdd +'" class="form-control inputTglClone">'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                        '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Code</label>'+
                        '<div class="col-sm-10">'+
                            '<select name="inputCode[]" id="inputCodeClone'+ runNumberAdd +'" class="form-control select2 inputCodeClone">'+
                            '</select>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                        '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Stasiun</label>'+
                        '<div class="col-sm-10">'+
                            '<select name="inputStasiun[]" id="inputStasiunClone'+ runNumberAdd +'" class="form-control select2 inputStasiunClone">'+
                            '</select>'+
                            '<input name="inputStasiunHidden[]" type="text" id="inputStasiunHiddenClone'+ runNumberAdd +'" class="form-control inputStasiunHiddenClone">'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                        '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Peralatan</label>'+
                        '<div class="col-sm-10">'+
                            '<select name="inputPeralatan[]" id="inputPeralatanClone'+ runNumberAdd +'" class="form-control select2 inputPeralatanClone">'+
                            '</select>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                        '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Deskripsi</label>'+
                        '<div class="col-sm-10">'+
                            '<textarea name="inputDeskripsi[]" id="inputDeskripsiClone'+ runNumberAdd +'" class="form-control inputDeskripsiClone"></textarea>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                        '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Resume</label>'+
                        '<div class="col-sm-10">'+
                            '<label class="radio-inline">'+
                                '<input type="radio" name="inputChecklist[]" id="inputChecklist1Clone'+ runNumberAdd +'" class="inputChecklist1Clone'+ runNumberAdd +'" value="1"> OK'+
                            '</label>'+
                            '<label class="radio-inline">'+
                                '<input type="radio" name="inputChecklist[]" id="inputChecklist2Clone'+ runNumberAdd +'" class="inputChecklist2Clone'+ runNumberAdd +'" value="0"> NOK'+
                            '</label>'+
                            '<div class="pull-right">'+
                                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove_list"> Hapus From Checklist</button>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>';
        $('.clone-form').append(html);
        $(".inputCodeClone, .inputStasiunClone, .inputPeralatanClone").select2({
            placeholder: "Choose one",
            allowClear: true
        });
        $.ajax({
            url   : 'showDataCode',
            dataType : 'JSON',
            async : true,
            success : function(data) {
                var minrunNumberAdd = runNumberAdd - 1;
                var attrCode = '#inputCodeClone' + minrunNumberAdd;
                $(attrCode).append($("<option selected disabled></option>").attr("value", '').text('')); 
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {   
                    $(attrCode).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value.id).text(value.code)); 
                });
            }
        });
        $('.btnSend').attr('disabled', false);
        $('.inputStasiunClone').attr("disabled", true);
        $('.inputPeralatanClone').attr("disabled", true);
        runNumberAdd++;
    });
    
    $("body").on("click", ".remove_list",function() {
        var numItems = $('.control-group').length;
        $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
        if (numItems == 1) {
            $('.btnSend').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('.btnSend').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
    
    
    
    
    // How to get attribut ID
    // My Xample
    $('input[id^="inputCodeClone"]').on('click', function() { 
        alert('A');
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="box-header">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <button type="button"  id="add-more" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"> Tambah From Checklist</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form action="<?= base_url('GeneralFormChecklist/submitChecklist'); ?>" method="post" id="formInput">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="clone-form">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-footer">
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnSend">Kirim Checklist</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Sample data in a database
[image: 1]

**The question is:**

1. how to be able to display id_location in the input station and id_equipment_name in the input equipment by selecting code as where in the database later?

**NOTE:** *the code that I have stuck when looking for a dynamic ID*

Comment: $('input[id^="inputCodeClone"]').on('click', function(e,value) { 
       //here get the value of selected option value
    });

Comment: @LDS nothing happens, even though you have been instructed to bring up an alert, 
there maybe an error in the selector, i am not sure

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the value of current input that you clicked or all the nearest inputs then you can use $(this).
it helps you to point on the currently focused or clicked element.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but if you click on the input, nothing happens, even though you have been instructed to bring up an alert

Comment: Is there something wrong with the selector? @Harsimranjit Singh

Comment: I suggest you to try with the class selector, then alert  $(this).val()   or provide me a JS fiddle or any other code snippet

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/473ehusm/1/ maybe you can try it @Harsimranjit Singh

Comment: @AdyShaputra you are initializing the select2 on your select element that's why you are unable to track any click on that because select2 disabled it.
 $('.inputCodeClone').on('select2:select', function (e) {
  // Do something
    alert('A');
   });

Comment: by the way thanks for helping and responding @Harsimranjit Singh

Comment: Please add some data in your tabs and then use select2  selector https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

Comment: but it's still the same as not raising an alert with the syntax you provided @Harsimranjit Singh

Comment: add some data in select boxed

Comment: oh okay wait a minute i will add the data first @Harsimranjit Singh

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/473ehusm/2/ box already filled with data @Harsimranjit Singh

Comment: I added the code to your JS fiddle, Bro the problem is that you are adding whole HTML form dynamically and your js loads before it.    please review your fiddle code. and you need to call your js after the HTML load

Comment: Your DOM(Document object model) must be ready before js or jquery function to be performed

Answer (score 0):

I just try to add some fields .You modify

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box-header">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <button type="button"  id="add-more" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"> Tambah From Checklist</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form action="<?= base_url('GeneralFormChecklist/submitChecklist'); ?>" method="post" id="formInput">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="clone-form">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-footer">
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnSend">Kirim Checklist</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var html = '';


    $('.btnSend').attr('disabled', true);

    $("#inputCode, #inputStasiun, #inputPeralatan").select2({
        placeholder: "Choose one",
        allowClear: true
    });

    var runNumberAdd = 1;
    $("#add-more").click(function() {
 html =  $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'col-sm-6 control-group'
    });
 var firstchild =  $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'form-group'
    });
   var lable1 =  $('<label/>', {
        'class': 'col-sm-2 control-label',
 text: 'Tanggal',
 id: 'lbl1'
    }).on('click',function(){
 alert("First lable");
});
var innerchild =  $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'col-sm-10'
 
    });
var firstinput =  $('<input/>', {
        'class': 'form-control inputTglClone',
 id: 'inputTglClone'+ runNumberAdd,
 type: 'date' 
    });
innerchild.append(firstinput);
firstchild.append(lable1);
firstchild.append(innerchild);

 html.append(firstchild);
 
  var lable2 =  $('<label/>', {
        'class': 'col-sm-2 control-label',
 text: 'Code',
 id: 'lbl2'
    }).on('click',function(){
 alert("First lable");
});
 runNumberAdd = 2;
        var firstselectinput =  $('<select/>', {
        'class': 'form-control select2 inputCodeClone',
 id: 'inputTglClone_select',
 
    });
var innerchild1 =  $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'col-sm-10'
 
    });
var secondchild =  $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'form-group'
    });
 innerchild1.append(firstselectinput);
 secondchild.append(lable2);
 secondchild.append(innerchild1);
 html.append(secondchild);  
        $('.clone-form').html(html);
        $(".inputCodeClone, .inputStasiunClone, .inputPeralatanClone").select2({
            placeholder: "Choose two",
            allowClear: true,
     data:[{id:'1',text:'one'},{id:'2',text:'two'}],
 createTag: function (params) {
      var term = $.trim(params.term);
      if (term === '') {
        return null;
      }
      return {id: term,text: term}
      
  }
        }).on("change", function (e) {
 var selectedvalue = e.currentTarget.selectedOptions[0].value;
 alert(selectedvalue);
 
});
       
        $('.btnSend').attr('disabled', false);
        $('.inputStasiunClone').attr("disabled", true);
        $('.inputPeralatanClone').attr("disabled", true);
        runNumberAdd++;
    });
   
    $("body").on("click", ".remove_list",function() {
        var numItems = $('.control-group').length;
        $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
        if (numItems == 1) {
            $('.btnSend').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('.btnSend').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
    
  
   
   
 
});
</script
</body>
```